# column with two types

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a dataframe with one column, `col1`.

```
#ds
col1
1001
  27
1004
0000

ds.dtpyes
col1  object
```

However, in this column, python identifies `1001, 27, 1004` as `float` and `0000` as `str`.

I want to substring the column like this:

```
#ds
col1   col_new
1001        10
  27        00
1004        10
0000        00
  10        00
```

But I got `NaN`:

```
ds['col_new'] = ds['col1'].str[:2]

#ds
col1   col_new
1001       NaN
  27       NaN
1004       NaN
0000        00
```

Any help? Thanks!

**UPDATED**
I edited to example to make it more clear.
For those who only have two digits, I need to fill '00' in front of them.
For example, '27' to be '0027'.

**ANSWER**:

```
ds['col1'].astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(4).str[:2]
```

Comment: Why should 1001 and 1004 become 10 if they are float?

Comment: leading zeros are not valid for integers FYI

Comment: `df['col1'].astype(str).str[:2].str.zfill(2)`

Comment: @Chris Your solution is great. But I edited the question to make it more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `[:2]` to retain the first 2 characters of each row is correct when dealing with strings, as you previously mentioned, since the first 3 values are being treated as `float` then you would need to previously convert the full row to string with `.astype(str)`. Furthermore, if you have values that have less than 4 characters, we can use `pad` to actually fill the left-side with 0s before extracting the first 2 characters.

Therefore, I would do the following:

```
df['col1'].astype(str).str.pad(width=4,side='left',fillchar='0').str[:2]
```

Which outputs:

```
0    10
1    00
2    10
3    00
```

Full reproducible exapmle:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1001,27,1004,'0000']})
df['col1'].astype(str).str.pad(width=4,side='left',fillchar='0').str[:2]
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. `27` should be considered as `0027` so it should be `00` in `col_new`

Comment: Thank you for the comment, try this answer please.

Comment: not get the correct result for `27`... I still got `27` instead of `00`

Comment: I got 00... Please copy and paste the code

Comment: I think the problem is:  in this column, python identifies `1001, 27, 1004` as `float` and `0000` as `str`.

Comment: If I did it like this: `ds.iloc[1,0].astype(str)` I got `AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'astype'`

Comment: Because you are selecting a single element, not the column. Should try `ds.iloc[:,0]` in any case

Comment: I copy and paste your code: `df['col1'].astype(str).str.pad(width=4,side='left',fillchar='0')` and I even got `1001.0, 27.0, 1004.0, 0000`

Comment: That is not my full code, you are missing `.str[:2]` ....

Comment: I know I miss that but I got `27` so after I added that I still got `27`

Comment: Then the data you are using is not the same as the one you are providing for the example. As you can see from my full reproducible example, the code is functional.

Comment: I figured it out: `ds['col1'].astype(int).astype(str).str.zfill(4).str[:2]`

Answer (score 0):

use the `astype` method to convert all the values in the column to be strings. Then when you call .str[:2] they all should be have as expected.

```
ds['col_new'] = ds['col1'].astype(str).str[:2]
```